# Player rotates,Camera rotates, but x,y,z stay the same?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am moving the camera around as so

```c#
public static CameraController Instance{ set; get; }

    public Transform lookAt;
    public Transform camTransform;

    private Camera cam;

    public const float Y_ANGLE_MIN = 0.0f;
    public const float Y_ANGLE_MAX = 50.0f;
    public float distance = 10.0f;
    public float currentX = 0.0f;
    public float currentY = 0.0f;
    public float sensitivityX = 7.0f;
    public float sensitivityY = 7.0f;

    private void Start(){
        Instance = this;
        camTransform = transform;
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    private void Update(){
        currentX += InputManager.SecondaryHorizontal ();
        currentY += InputManager.SecondaryVertical ();

        currentY = Mathf.Clamp (currentY, Y_ANGLE_MIN, Y_ANGLE_MAX);
    }

    private void LateUpdate(){
        Vector3 dir = new Vector3 (0, 0, -distance);
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentY,currentX,0);
        camTransform.position = lookAt.position + rotation * dir;
        camTransform.LookAt (lookAt.position);
        this.transform.position += Vector3.up;
    }
```

I am rotating my player around as the camera rotates as so

```c#
private void Update(){
        this.transform.eulerAngles = CameraController.Instance.camTransform.eulerAngles;
        }
```

I am expecting that when my player is rotated to the left that pressing the `MainVertical()`  (attached to the WASD controls & joystick X,Y axis)

```c#
public static float MainVertical(){
        float r = 0.0f;
        r += Input.GetAxis ("J_MainVertical");
        r += Input.GetAxis ("K_MainVertical");
        return Mathf.Clamp (r, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    }
```

will rotate move the player forward in the direction that is now the `forward` direction

However the character continues to move forward in what was originally the `forward` direction.

I can only assume that the issue is though the forward axis has changed for the object the x,y,z in world space doesnt change and thats what `MainVertical()` is still accessing

As requested here is the code for my character movement

```c#
private CharacterController controller;
    private Animator anim;

    //Speed settings
    private float walkingSpeed = 5.0f;
    private float runningSpeed = 7.5f;

    //Jump and gravity settings
    private float verticalVelocity;
    private float gravity = 14.0f;
    private float jumpForce = 10.0f;

    private void Start(){
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    private void Update(){
        this.transform.eulerAngles = CameraController.Instance.camTransform.eulerAngles;
        Jump ();

        Vector3 moveVector = InputManager.MainJoystick ();
        moveVector.x = moveVector.x * walkingSpeed;
        moveVector.y = verticalVelocity;
        moveVector.z = moveVector.z * walkingSpeed;
        controller.Move (moveVector * Time.deltaTime);

        Vector3 camForward = Vector3.Scale (CameraController.Instance.camTransform.forward, new Vector3 (1, 0, 1)).normalized;


        if (moveVector.x != 0 || moveVector.z != 0) {
            anim.SetBool ("IsIdle", false);
            anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", true);
        } else {
            anim.SetBool ("IsIdle", true);
            anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", false);
        }
    }

    protected void Jump(){
        if (controller.isGrounded) {
            verticalVelocity = -gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            if (InputManager.AButton()) {
                anim.SetTrigger ("Jump");
                verticalVelocity = jumpForce;
            }
        } else {
            verticalVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            //anim.SetTrigger ("Landing");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my input manager

```c#
    // -- Axis

    public static float MainHorizontal(){
        float r = 0.0f;
        r += Input.GetAxis ("J_MainHorizontal");
        r += Input.GetAxis ("K_MainHorizontal");
        return Mathf.Clamp (r, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    public static float MainVertical(){
        float r = 0.0f;
        r += Input.GetAxis ("J_MainVertical");
        r += Input.GetAxis ("K_MainVertical");
        return Mathf.Clamp (r, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    public static Vector3 MainJoystick(){
        return new Vector3 (MainHorizontal (), 0, MainVertical ());
    }

    public static float SecondaryHorizontal(){
        float r = 0.0f;
        r += Input.GetAxis ("J_SecondaryHorizontal");
        r += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X");
        return Mathf.Clamp (r, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    public static float SecondaryVertical(){
        float r = 0.0f;
        r += Input.GetAxis ("J_SecondaryVertical");
        r += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y");
        return Mathf.Clamp (r, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    public static Vector3 SecondaryJoystick(){
        return new Vector3 (SecondaryHorizontal (), SecondaryVertical (), 0);
    }

    // -- Buttons

    public static bool AButton(){
        return Input.GetButtonDown ("A_Button");
    }

    public static bool BButton(){
        return Input.GetButtonDown ("B_Button");
    }

    public static bool XButton(){
        return Input.GetButtonDown ("X_Button");
    }

    public static bool YButton(){
        return Input.GetButtonDown ("Y_Button");
    }
```

Comment: can we see the code that moves the player forward and where `MainVertical()` is called?

Comment: updated question @JinJi

Comment: i think you are cofusing `this.transform` from player and `Input.GetAxis` - they are 2 totally different things, unrelated to each other. imagine FIFA, where you have 11 soccer players, each has his own `this.transform` but you still have only 1 `Input.GetAxis`

Comment: either use a Matrix to apply `CameraController.Instance.camTransform.eulerAngles` to `Vector3 moveVector` - or - move the player by modifying `this.transform.position`, without `controller.Move`

Answer (score 2):

this is correct:

> I can only assume that the issue is though the forward axis has
>   changed for the object the x,y,z in world space doesnt change and
>   thats what MainVertical() is still accessing

you are confusing `this.transform` from player and `Input.GetAxis` - they are 2 totally different things, unrelated to each other. imagine FIFA, where you have 11 soccer players, each has his own `this.transform` but you still have only one `Input.GetAxis`

try this:

```
private void Update(){
    this.transform.eulerAngles = CameraController.Instance.camTransform.eulerAngles;

    //Vector3 moveVector = Quaternion.Euler(this.transform.eulerAngles) * InputManager.MainJoystick ();

    // EDIT
    Vector3 moveVector = InputManager.MainJoystick ();
    moveVector = transform.TransformDirection(moveVector);

    moveVector.x = moveVector.x * walkingSpeed;
    moveVector.y = verticalVelocity;
    moveVector.z = moveVector.z * walkingSpeed;

    controller.Move (moveVector * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

in general, try to separate your player code from your input code - try to imagine how you would control 11 soccer players with 1 controller

EDIT:
used code from https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html

Comment: So this makes my character spin really fast and fall over spinning